# Consul doesn't show Health

Tags: spring-boot, consul

I couldn't check health of my services after the new spring boot upgrade from 1.5x to 2.x. I tried to call /health endpoint which throws an error, then view some spring boot article which said I need to call /actuator/health, then it shows

```
{"status":"UP"}
```

I have added this property `"management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS"` then it shows something like this.

```
{"status":"UNKNOWN","details":{"binders":{"status":"UNKNOWN","details":{"consul":{"status":"UNKNOWN"}}},"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","details":{"total":254447448064,"free":149837242368,"threshold":10485760}},"db":{"status":"UP","details":"database":"Oracle","hello":"Hello"}},"refreshScope":{"status":"UP"},"discoveryComposite":{"status":"UNKNOWN","details":{"discoveryClient":{"status":"UP","details":{"services":[]}}}},"clientConfigServer":{"status":"UP","details":{"propertySources":[]}},"hystrix":{"status":"UP"}}}
```

Can some one let me know, what properties need to be added to see the status instead of "UNKNOWN". Thanks in advance.